# Crop video with FFMPEG based on data from tracking algorithm

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have tracked a moving object in a video file using [OpenTLD](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD). This generated a file with the coordinates of the object's bounding box for each frame.

Now I would like to use `ffmpeg` to crop the video to a box centered on that object. I have seen that the [crop filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) has `x` and `y` options to specify the position of the crop box. I would like to specify these coordinates individually for each frame based on the coordinates in my tracking file.

Does `ffmpeg` offer a possibility to specify such filter parameters per frame, or read filter parameters for individual frames from a file?

Comment: Your best bet might be to export the frames to stills, then run the crop over the stills, then join them all back together as an image again.

Comment: @kassiopeia I'm a little late for this, but is there any chance you managed to get this working?

Comment: @Alex actually I ended up doing what Paul suggested... exporting all frames to stills, then have ffmpeg crop each still individually and finally reassemble them into a video